# how to use virtual rule or regexp for virtual_user on postfix

Tags: postfix-mta

I have created a email system with virtual users, postfix, dovecot and roundcube.

I want following rule to be implemented for my subdomains.

users at abc.domain.com can send/receive email to/from abc.domain.com only

users at xyz.domain.com can send/receive email to/from xyz.domain.com only

users at aab.domain2.com can send/receive email to/from aab.domain2.com only

I found out, it can be done by header_check or writing virtual transport. I tried with if (sender_domain) != (receiver_domain) REJECT its not working.

When working with virtual transport, i have no idea how it will be done. Please help.

regexp and virtual users

Comment: Basically i wanted to allow users to send email to their own sub domain only

Comment: is it possible to write header check like \n                                                                             if (wild_card) sender_domain != receipient_domain REJECT email                                          /^From:[[:space:]]+(.*)/ REPLACE From: ">${1}<" /^To